# Allow DNS Resolution Across Multiple Internal Domains on Windows ADC

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domaincontroller

I have a client running multiple internal domains - for ease I'll refer to them as **CORP.local** and **PROD.local**. Is there a way to allow DNS resolution for clients in **CORP.local** to resolve hosts in **PROD.local**?

Comment: This was ultimately the right answer; there were other issues preventing it from working initially - but in a lab environment worked precisely as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.  On the DNS server authoritative for CORP.local, configure conditional forwarding to PROD.local.  In this configuration, all DNS queries for hosts in PROD.LOCAL will be forwarded to the PROD.local DNS server for name resolution instead.  There are other methods as well, but this method in my opinion is the easiest.

[How to Create a Conditional Forwarder on a Windows DNS Server](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN164002/EN)